# Magento updates caused site to break

Tags: magento-1.7, error, usps

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_FUNCTION in /homepages/34/d512863470/htdocs/thriftyhorse/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php on line 240

I updated some components of Magento since I was having trouble integrating USPS and thought that would help. Then I got the following issue. I saw this answer
[Cron error on line 240 from Mage/Core/Helper/Abstract.php](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61628/cron-error-on-line-240-from-mage-core-helper-abstract-php)

It seems like the same problem, but I don't know how change the cron command. With my hosting, I cannot do it through the CPANEL as I've seen in other answers, only through PuTTy.

Comment: Sounds like time to contact your hosting provider and ask for help as they're more familiar with how they set the system up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends on your OS and version of crontab, I guess, but you can edit cron jobs with the `crontab -e` command. [This answer](https://serverfault.com/questions/206105/how-to-add-a-cron-via-ssh) states:

`crontab -e` is used to edit the cron entries for the current user. See the `crontab(1)` and `crontab(5)` man pages for more details.

A short Google search for "ssh edit cronjob" or similar reveals more information.