# Mandrill cron error

Tags: magento-1.9

I get this error in my cron.log and as a result no emails seem to work:

> PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '[' in
>   /var/www/vhosts/gsequestrian.co.uk/httpdocs/app/code/community/Ebizmarts/Mandrill/Model/Email/Queue.php
>   on line 35

Link to code: https://www.dropbox.com/s/ecnwecmi8pwx9be/Queue.php?dl=0

Section starting line 35:

```
$mandrill = [
                    'subject' => $parameters->getSubject(),
                    'to' => [],
                    'from_email' => $parameters->getFromEmail(),
                    'from_name' => $parameters->getFromName(),
                    'headers' => $mailer->getHeaders(),
                    'html' => ($parameters->getIsPlain() ? "" : $message->getMessageBody()),
                    'text' => ($parameters->getIsPlain() ? $message->getMessageBody() : ""),
                ];
```

Comment: What version of PHP are you on? Using [] is only supported in PHP 5.4+

Comment: I'm using PHP version 5.5.33.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a syntax error because you are running an outdated PHP version which does not support short array notation. This version of the Mandrill extension obviously does not support PHP 5.3

The only reasonable solution is to update to PHP 5.5 or 5.6, depending on your Magento version. They added 5.6 support with Magento 1.9.1

Comment: I'm using PHP 5.5.33.

Comment: Your cronjob does not. Many hosters run a different PHP version on the command line.

Comment: Similar problem: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/61628/cron-error-on-line-240-from-mage-core-helper-abstract-php/61735#61735

Comment: Ok as per that link can I change my CRON command so that it knows to use 5.5?  THis is what I have currently as the command:  /opt/plesk/php/5.5/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/gsequestrian.co.uk/httpdocs/cron.php >> /var/www/vhosts/gsequestrian.co.uk/httpdocs/var/log/cron.log 2>&1

Comment: That looks like it should use PHP 5.5 but because the mode parameter is missing, it will probably trigger cron.sh which in turn runs "php" without specified path. Change the command to `/opt/plesk/php/5.5/bin/php -f /var/www/vhosts/gsequestrian.co.uk/httpdocs/cron.php -- -mdefault >> /var/www/vhosts/gsequestrian.co.uk/httpdocs/var/log/cron.log 2>&1` to prevent this

Comment: Brilliant thank you!!  Transactional emails are now working.